# wp_nav_menu dont return proper values

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, navigation

Im making custom wordpress theme based on underscore theme. I have problem with outputing my navigation parameters given in functions work not exacly like it is said in Wordpress documentation and im getting confused more and more.

So first of here is my function:

```
  wp_nav_menu( array (
                'theme_location' => 'mobile',
                'container' => 'div',
                'container_class' => 'test',
                'menu_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'menu_id' => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'

                ));
```

Here is my HTML with this what i want to achieve :

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

And here is what i recieve when i use function posted above

```
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/jlvwp/index.php/przykladowa-strona/">Przykładowa strona</a></li></ul></div>
```

So this what i recieve its completly diffrent with this what is in [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/). First of `menu_id / menu_class` is suppose to add class/id to `ul` tag and instead its adding class/id to container. Secound `container_class` simply do not work and im unable to add class to my `<ul>` tag. I beg for help im more then confused.

Comment: You misspelled container_class, is this your actual code?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, in code it is correct, that is not an issue, as i said - for example menu_id/menu_class works like container_class according to wp documentation. And yes, this is my actual code.